# asp:Login doesn't caused event OnLoggingIn if another objekt caused postback before

Tags: asp.net, login-control

I have on MasterPage:

`<asp:Login ID="lgLogin" runat="server" OnLoggingIn="lgLogin_OnLoggingIn" />`

and on normal page I have:

`<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" AutoPostBack="true" />`

If I do login action first, there is no problem.
If I change DDL items, it causes postback. And after that, login does't work. It causes postback, but doesn't call lgLogin_OnLoggingIn method.